# Personalize Nominatim web page

Tags: php, linux, openlayers, openstreetmap, nominatim

When I install Nominatim with the help of this [guide](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation), it creates a website automatically. I wonder how I can change the website as I would like it.

```
osm@debian:/var/www/nominatim$ ls
css            details.php  index.php  polygons.php  search.php
deletable.php  images       js         reverse.php   status.php
```

There is no file HTML. Is it created by php?

Comment: index.php is the page...

Answer (score 0):

What about creating another page using different [web widgets](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks) that just call your nominatim instance?

Answer (score -1):

You can change anything from your nominatim/lib/templates folder
Here you can find  .html files which you will need to change.